# Laravel Mix with Functional Javascript

Tags: javascript, webpack, laravel-mix

I want to write Javascript with the classical functional way. I know there are lots of great features with modern Javascript but because I'm a backend developer, I don't want to spend my time with learning modern Javascript. I use jQuery and it's more than enough for me to write classical functional Javascript.

```
function someSimpleFunction() {
    // do some simple stuff
}
```

So here's the problem. When I write functional Javascript, Laravel Mix removes all my functions. It's probably because of Webpack (which I'm not sure) but I want all my functions remain in the final compiled JS file.

How can I prevent Laravel Mix or Webpack to remove my Javascript functions?

Here is my **simplifed** `webpack.mix.js` file.

```
mix.less('resources/assets/less/app.less', 'public/assets/css')
    .options({processCssUrls: false})
    .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/assets/js/app.js')
    .copyDirectory('resources/assets/img', 'public/assets/img');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

And here is my **simplified** `resources/assets/js/app.js` file

```
require('./functions.js');
require('./events.js');
// some other js files
```

Comment: Burak ne haber dostum, seni "js" ye devam ediyor görmek güzel .. :)